# BitmapFacotry.decodeByteArray returns null for a valid image's byte array

Tags: android, bitmap

this is an image in the tag of an mp3 file
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtXqA.jpg

i get this image byte array from mp3 file with Android's MediaMetaDataRetreiver ... when i try to decode this image using BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray it returns null

Help would be apprecciated

EDIT: when i first decode with options.inJustDecodeBounds = true ... options.outWidth and options.outHeight returns the correct width and height

Full Code:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(context, songUri);
        byte[] data = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        if(data != null)
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
            options.inSampleSize = BitmapUtils.calculateInSampleSize(options, 500, 500);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            albumArtBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
        }
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: did do positively verified that the byte[] is in fact the file you linked? (e.g. by dumping it to the file system, or measuring a checksum on it)

Comment: can you log the value you retrieve for inSampleSize?\

Comment: @njzk2 ... i dumped the byte array to sd as jpg ... android couldn't show the image (QuickPic -> Load Failed) ... but when i send this to my computer the image showed correctly ... so wtf 
Edit: yes the file is the same as the one i posted

Comment: @njzk2 ... the value for inSampleSize was 4 and in logcat there was a log with tag="skia" and its text="---decoder->decode returned false"

Comment: it is possible that your image cannot be decoded by android without an external jpeg library

Answer (score 1):

Use stream instead:

```
InputStream is;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.someImage);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    try {
        is.close();
        is = null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

BTW, I didn't try jpg yet but suppose maybe this is a problem. Try to convert it to "png"

Comment: this image is extracted from a mp3 file's tag ... can't get a stream for it ... only byte array ... and btw i also tried using ByteArrayInputStream for the byte array and decode it using BitmapFactory.decodeStream and it didn't work